# How to connect to tableview containers?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, core-data

I am a beginner to Xcode and Swift and I am currently creating an application where the user adds a person on the application and after that it right the amount of money they owe that person or that person owes him/her.

Note: I have used core data to store all the value

I have ViewController called PeopleTableViewController where the user adds the name of the person they owe. Then I have PersonDetailTableViewController which shows the list of details the user owes that particular person the selected in PeopleTableViewController. The problem I am facing is that if I add three people in PeopleTableViewController and when I select any one of the people then I am directed to same tableview in PersonDetailTableViewController but I want different tableviews for different person the user selects in PeopleTableViewController.

PersonDetailTableViewController:

```
import UIKit

class PersonDetailTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext


    var totalLabel: UILabel?
    var person: People?
    var owe: Owe?

    @IBOutlet var personTable: UITableView!

    var dataInfo: [Owe] = []
    var selectedObject: [Owe] = []
    var balanceAmount = "Balance: "

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return (dataInfo.count)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = personTable
            .dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "detailsCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = dataInfo[indexPath.row].name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "₹ \(dataInfo[indexPath.row].amount)"
//        if dataInfo[indexPath.row].amount < 0 {
//            cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.red
//        } else {
//            cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.green
//        }
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedObject = [dataInfo[indexPath.row]]
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "addOweDetails", sender: nil)
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        getData()
        personTable.dataSource = self
        addTotalToNav()
        print(dataInfo as Any)
    }



    // MARK: - Table view data source

    func addTotalToNav() -> Void {
        if let navigationBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar {
            let totalFrame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 0, width: navigationBar.frame.width/2, height: navigationBar.frame.height)

            totalLabel = UILabel(frame: totalFrame)
            totalLabel?.text = balanceAmount
            totalLabel?.tag = 1
            totalLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
            totalLabel?.textColor = UIColor.red
//            navigationBar.large = totalLabel?.text
            self.title = totalLabel?.text

        }
    }


    func getData() -> Void {
        do{
            dataInfo = try context.fetch(Owe.fetchRequest())
            var total:Double = 0.00
            for i in 0 ..< dataInfo.count {
                total += dataInfo[i].amount as! Double
            }
            balanceAmount = "Balance: ₹" + (NSString(format: "%.2f", total as CVarArg) as String)
        }
        catch{
            print("Fetching Failed")
        }
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let vc = segue.destination as! NewOweTableViewController
        vc.dataInfo = selectedObject
        selectedObject.removeAll()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        getData()
        personTable.reloadData()
        if (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.viewWithTag(1)?.isHidden == true){
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.viewWithTag(1)?.removeFromSuperview()
            addTotalToNav()
        }
    }

}
```

PeopleTableViewController:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class PeopleTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var peopleTableView: UITableView!

    var people: [People] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        peopleTableView.separatorStyle = .none

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
    }

    //ViewWillAppear allows us to fetch all the data in the backend and help us display to the user
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
        }

        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<People> =  People.fetchRequest()

        do {
            people = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)

            peopleTableView.reloadData()
        } catch {
            print("Could not fetch")
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    }

    //Following function is called right before the user segues from one viewcontroller to another viewcontroller

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        guard let destination = segue.destination as? PersonDetailTableViewController,
           let selectedRow = self.peopleTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row else {
            return
        }

        destination.person = people[selectedRow]
//        destination.owe = people[selectedRow]

    }

    func deletePerson(at indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let person = people[indexPath.row]

        guard let managedContext = person.managedObjectContext else {
            return
        }

        managedContext.delete(person)

        do {
            try managedContext.save()

            people.remove(at: indexPath.row)

            peopleTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        } catch {
            print("Could not delete")

            peopleTableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        }
    }
}

extension PeopleTableViewController{

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return people.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = peopleTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "peopleCell", for: indexPath)

        let person = people[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = person.title

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            deletePerson(at: indexPath)
        }
    }
}
```

The following images shows what I exactly require:

PeopleTableViewController

[PeopleTableViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1rYt.png)

On clicking Mike I get following:

[PersonDetailTableViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYGAZ.png)

On clicking John I get following:

[PersonDetailTableViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixbdK.png)

I want that the records for Mike and John should be different that is on PersonDetailTableViewController.

Answer (score 1):

You can try (Both in `PeopleTableViewController`) , create a segue named `shoePersonDetails` from `PeopleTableViewController` to `PersonDetailTableViewController`

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let person = people[indexPath.row]
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "shoePersonDetails", sender: person)
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

//

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let vc = segue.destination as! PersonDetailTableViewController
    vc.dataInfo = sender as! People

}
```

Comment: Hi Sh_Khan, Thanks for your answer but it is giving "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" error at let vc = segue.destination as! NewOweTableViewController. And following is the error:                    Could not cast value of type 'Draft3.PersonDetailTableViewController' (0x10a943c48) to 'Draft3.NewOweTableViewController' (0x10a943958).
2018-03-27 22:06:52.780804+0530 Draft3[71618:3274381] Could not cast value of type 'Draft3.PersonDetailTableViewController' (0x10a943c48) to 'Draft3.NewOweTableViewController' (0x10a943958).

Comment: Also, override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let vc = segue.destination as! NewOweTableViewController
    vc.dataInfo = sender as! Owe }                                                                        Is this for PeopleViewController

Comment: see edit ........... , Also clarify please is that what you want or where do you want to navigate from and to what ????

Comment: It's still not working cuz it's giving the error : Cannot assign value of type 'People' to type '[Owe]'

Comment: ok it's clear now , when say you click on Mike , do you search coredata for it's data ??? or there is not filtering according to the name , i see only array of people in peopleVC ??

Comment: Yeah that's correct so I am not able to do the filtering process. Can you please help me